# Codeception call to undefined method assertEquals

Tags: php, codeception

I'm at the beginning of my Codeception adventure.
I ran into a problem assigning the assertEquals() method even though I declared it
`use PHPUnit\Framework\Assert;`

Code test:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Product\TestApi;
use Product\ApiTester;
use Codeception\Util\HttpCode;
use PHPUnit\Framework\Assert;
public function CreateProduct(ApiTester $I)
    {
        $I->sendPost('/api/product/');
        $I->seeResponseCodeIs(HttpCode::CREATED);

        $responsePost = $I->grabDataFromResponseByJsonPath('$..product');
        $I-$this->assertEquals(4,strlen((string)$responsePost));

        $I->seeResponseContainsJson(
            [
                'category' => 'main',
                'product' => 'fish',
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

I am getting an error:

```
api/CreateProductCest.php:createProduct
                                                                                              
  [Error] Call to undefined method Product\TestApi\CreateProductCest::assertEquals()  
                                                                                              

Scenario Steps:

 3. $I->grabDataFromResponseByJsonPath("$..product") at api/CreateProductCest.php:42
 2. $I->seeResponseCodeIs(201) at api/CreateProductCest.php:41
 1. $I->sendPost("/api/product/") at api/CreateProductCest.php:40

#1  /product-service/modules/Product/tests/api/CreateProductCest.php:43
#2  Product\TestApi\CreateProductCest->createProduct
Artifacts:

Body: {"id":3,"product":"fish","category":"main"}
```

Answer (score 2):

`$this->assertEquals` is not available in Cest format, you have to enable Asserts module in suite configuration file and then use `$I->assertEquals`.

api.suite.yaml:

```
actor: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Asserts
        - REST:
            depends: PhpBrowser
```